# Doctrine mapping import global namespace for associations

Tags: namespaces, doctrine, symfony

Trying to import a mapping from my database

```
$ php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import MyBundle annotation
```

Here is one of my associations generated from a foreign key by Doctrine

```php
/**
 * @var \CustomerSite
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="CustomerSite")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer_site_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $customerSite;
```

As you can see the field is referenced in the global namespace

```
@var \CustomerSite
```

It should be

```
@var CustomerSite
```

Why does doctrine use the global namespace here ? How do I tell it not to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of such things that could be greatly improved in the [`EntityGenerator`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.4/class-Doctrine.ORM.Tools.EntityGenerator.html) and related utilities.
And no, there is nothing to get around this, you just have to change it manually.

An other common example, if you have the two following entities:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Tag")
     */
    private $tags;
}

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

class Tag
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;
}
```

Then, if you execute `doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle:Product`, the generated result will be:

```
/**
 * Add tag
 *
 * @param \App\SportBundle\Entity\Tag $tag
 *
 * @return Sport
 */
public function addTag(\App\SportBundle\Entity\Tag $tag)
{
    $this->tags[] = $tag;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove tag
 *
 * @param \App\SportBundle\Entity\Tag $tag
 */
public function removeTag(\App\SportBundle\Entity\Tag $tag)
{
    $this->tags->removeElement($tag);
}

/**
 * Get tags
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getTags()
{
    return $this->tags;
}
```

But it should be:

```
/**
 * Add tag
 *
 * @param Tag $tag
 *
 * @return Sport
 */
public function addTag(Tag $tag)
{
    $this->tags[] = $tag;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove tag
 *
 * @param Tag $tag
 */
public function removeTag(Tag $tag)
{
    $this->tags->removeElement($tag);
}

/**
 * Get tags
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getTags()
{
    return $this->tags;
}
```

I think that some simple checks are missing in the entity generation behavior.
I already proposed a [PR](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/5733) about a totally different problem (methods naming of the generated entities for non-plural members) but that is part of the same behavior. After almost a month, nothing happens.

But I think this issue would be more considered because of it's a common and real problem that the generated typehints/phpdocs are not the expected.

Please keep us informed if you open one.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following two commands before creating getters/setters:

```
sed -i'' -e 's/@var \\/@var /g' src/Entity/*.php
sed -i'' -e 's/@var Datetime/@var \\Datetime/g' src/Entity/*.php
```